# C# Update method

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

I want to make a small game using System.drawing, but got stuck when trying to create an (XNA or other game engine like) Update method that is called many times per second.

First I tried to make my own Update with System.Timers, but the screen started to flicker even if I checked if the Paint event of my form was done drawing.

Now I have been searching for a library that allows me to do that, but with no luck. For example, XNA doesn't allow me to use some kind of drawing like System.drawing does and other libraries like that only accept 'non-resizable graphics'.

My questions are: Can I create an efficient Update method on my own? Is there a library that can do what I want to do?

Comment: you need to backbuffer if it's flickering, it has nothing to do with using system timers

Comment: I already did that, but the timer seems to go to fast to repaint the whole form again everytime (15 ms)

Comment: hat is called "not using a back buffer".

Comment: Is there some real reason you can't use OpenTK or XNA? You say your goal is to `use some kind of drawing like System.drawing`. I know that OpenTK has functions for rectangles and linestrips, inherited from OpenGL itself. Do you really **need** `System.Drawing`? Overall I'm having a hard time understanding your issues, because of how they're worded. You aren't giving enough information, either - just vague mentions of things not working.

Comment: I want to make a simple **2D** game and the backbuffer is probably going to work, but I'm still working on that.

Comment: Not sure why you bolded **2D**; OpenTK's default project is 2D and has an update method. System.Drawing is just the wrong tool.

Comment: http://www.opentk.com/ says: "The Open Toolkit is an advanced, low-level C# library that wraps OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenAL. It is suitable for games, scientific applications and any other project that requires **3d graphics**, audio or compute functionality." Did I miss something?

Comment: 3 > 2. Supporting 2D might restrict 3D, but supporting 3D does not restrict 2D. The default project has the depth buffer disabled, and is therefore 2D.

Comment: Then I will consider using that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I create an efficient Update method on my own?

In C# - no by any sensible means. Problem is that whatever you do will run on the CPU an that is inefficient per defintion.

Your problem is that you are not using buffers. Do not update the live window - update another bitmap and then render that one on the window. Look up "Double Buffering" on google.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

has some explanation

the titel is:

How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls

Comment: "Problem is that whatever you do will run on the CPU" really?

Comment: Yes. Unless you magically manage to call the GPU from your own routine without going native. C# somehow can not call the GPU wihouzt using an interface and that interface is ruled out in the question (XNA, DIrectX etc.). He says "on my own" which means .NET code which means CPU.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I added 'DoubleBuffered = true;' to my form, but it only got worse. If there is something you need to know, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yeah. Can you program? What you did was not implement double buffering  for your own drawing. Randomly changing properties does not help. Start reading.

Comment: I thought GDI was partially hardware accelerated

Comment: But that is what he does not want to use. He asks for a self-implemented alternative to GDI - which is btw. ,quite extensively hardware accelerated.

Comment: oh I thought system.drawing sat on to of GDI, that was the source of my confusion

Comment: It does. But he says that is too slow for him. your confusion seems to be not reading the question.

Comment: no he doesn't say it's too slow for him

Comment: After making my own buffer, it worked. Thanks! (and sorry for some of my not so clever comments)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it. Draw to a bitmap, that's your backbuffer. And then set a picturebox's image to the backbuffer bitmap. Yeah use a picturebox it seems to handle flicker better than a form. Set the picturebox size mode to StretchImage and the image will fill the picturebox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap _backbuffer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _backbuffer = new Bitmap(600, 400);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_backbuffer))
        {
            //clear the backbuffer
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            //draw stuff for the next frame
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100));
        }
        //draw the backbuffer to the screen
        pictureBox1.Image = _backbuffer;
    }
}
```